# Not Able to assign value retrieved from SQL database to other variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm retrieving a list from a SQL database with following code :

```
 var matInList = db.MaterialInLists
                   .Where(m => m.PartName == "ABC" && 
                               m.Month == "July").ToList();
```

and I'm trying to get parameters of list with foreach loop like

```
 foreach (var quanIn in matInList)
 {
     string quant = quanIn.Quantity;
     string Date = quanIn.Date;
     totalIn = totalIn + Int32.Parse(quanIn.Quantity); 
 }
```

Problem is in foreach loop only 3rd line gets the correct data i.e. totalIn.
"quanIn.Quantity" & "quanIn.Date" show correct value in debug mode but it is not able to assign its value to left hand side variable.

`MaterialInList` class is this:

```
public partial class MaterialInList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Date is a type and you're using it as a variable name. change string Date to some other name